# Adding a batch of items to a product list (in-app products)

Tags: android, product, in-app

I'm trying to import a csv-sheet products, but keep getting an error related to incorrect indication of the country or currency. I tried to export csv with in-apps first, and then tried to import (upload) this document. But still the same errors. How can I avoid it?

UDP: Sorry, can`t attach an image, beacause I`m a new user...

Comment: without any code or error log no one can help you.

Comment: Error message: "Invalid price (country: [RU]; Product ID: [film_0])."

Comment: this is not sufficient to check your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I finally found some documentation with examples about this:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481?hl=en

**CSV syntax example**

```
Product ID,Published State,Purchase Type,Auto Translate,Locale; Title; Description,Auto Fill Prices,Price,Pricing Template ID
```

**Managed product examples**

Example 1:

```
basic_sleeping_potion,published,managed_by_android,false,en_US; Basic Sleeping Potion; Puts small creatures to sleep.; es_ES; Poción básica de dormir; Causa las criaturas pequeñas ir a dormir.,false,,4637138456024710495
```

Example 2:

```
standard_sleeping_potion, published,managed_by_android,false,en_US; Standard Sleeping Potion; Puts all creatures to sleep for 2 minutes.,true, 1990000,
```

Example 3:

```
invisibility_potion,published, managed_by_android,false,en_US; Invisibility Potion; Invisible to all enemies for 5 minutes.,false, US; 1990000; BR; 6990000; RU; 129000000; IN; 130000000; ID; 27000000000; MX; 37000000;
```

And even more detailed documentation is here:
http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html